# Why does transform: translateX affect a fixed element's height on mobile?

Tags: html, css

Just now I ran into a weird probelm, I have a fixed element with `height:100%`. Everything works well until I open Chrome Dev Tool and enter the **mobile debug mode**.I found in **mobile debug mode** the fixed element's height will not `100%` but a little overflows. After my repeated debugging, I found the sibling's `translateX` property affects the fixed element's height. And when I tweak the value of `translateX` property, the height of the fixed element changes too.
I simplified it into the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Fixed Element Height Not 100%</title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
      body {
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .a {
        transform: translateX(100px);
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
      }

      .b {
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="a"></div>

    <div class="b"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Could someone tell me that whether this is expected or not ? If this is expected and what causes this ?

Answer (score 2):

Remove 2nd body tag CSS, which is overflow:hidden and add that property to first body tag CSS, following code will help you.

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. This works because it also adds overflow: hidden to html tag.Just wonder what causes this ...

Comment: Welcome @wang, If you think that the answer helps you then please upvote and tickmark the answer so that answer will helpful for the other programmer friends too.

Comment: Thanks  I will upvode . And could you please tell me what causes this ?

Comment: Hi @wang, thank for the upvote, I think I am not sure that, but directly body tag CSS not using class we can only apply for once at a time. I said this because in your previous code which you can add 2 body css if you remove 1st body tag css that height:100% and width:100% . And apply only 1 body tag CSS which have property overflow:hidden that code will also help you. So I think for body tag CSS we can only app one time without class. No need to write width:100% and height:100%;

Answer (score 1):

not sure but try to use `vh` instead of `%`

thinks this article would be very interesting aswell for this matter:

https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/